# 'The account is disabled' in sql2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

[image]When I create database through vs 2008 then it display 'The account is disabled'.
How to solve it?

Comment: Does it work if you use a different interface?

Answer (score 1):

The account you are trying to connect with is currently disabled for login .

use the steps mentioned in the link http://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/